# Compare Date stored in varchar in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am comparing my date(string) using between with database table column Date(varchar).it is working but compare only date ignore month and year as in .

```
SELECT * from Report
SELECT * from Report WHERE Date BETWEEN '05-03-2019' AND '07-03-2019'
SELECT * FROM Report WHERE CAST(Date as DATE) BETWEEN CAST('05-02-2019' 
AS DATE) AND CAST('07-02-2019' AS DATE);
```

Comment: Simple:  Fix your data.  Don't store dates as strings.

Comment: That format simply can't be compared. Fix the data types. Use `date` if the field should only contain dates, `datetime2` otherwise. Casting is no solution. It will force the server to scan the *entire table* whether the columns are indexed or not. That's because the index was created based on the original text

Comment: Besides, is that May 3rd or March 5th? You can *never* know with a text value, unless it's something clearly invalid for one format or the other. That makes storing the wrong date *very* easy. Once the dates get mixed up like this there's no easy way to recover them